# Aync function within another async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, geolocation, fetch

I am surprised by this so would like some guidance on what I am doing wrong here with the usage of Async Await syntax.

The 'getUserLocation' function returns the user's location:

```
  getUserLocation = async () => {
    const response = await window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      coord =>  ( coord.coords),
      err => {
        const { code, msg } = err;
        if (code === 1) {
          prompt(
            "Location is needed to get the local salah time, please try again.",
            msg
          );
        } else if (code === 2 || code === 3) {
          prompt(
            "Sorry, something went wrong, please try again or try again later.",
            msg
          );
        }
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
      }
    );
    // this.setState({
    //   userLocation: response,
    // });
    return response;
  };

  fetchTimes = async () => {
    const { userLocation, method, month, year } = this.state;
    const { lattitude, longitude } = userLocation;
    if (!lattitude) {
      let ress = await this.getUserLocation();
      console.log("ress: ", ress);
      const url = `http://api.address?latitude=${lattitude}&longitude=${longitude}&method=${method}&month=${month}&year=${year}`;
      console.log("url:", url);
      const resp = await fetch(url);
     ....
```

Even though the 'getUserLocation is called using 'await' keyword, however, the console reports that the `fetch` call is made before the user has been prompted for access to location & that location is returned to the fetchTimes function. Why is it not waiting for the `getUserLocation` to return the location first before proceeding with the `fetch` call?

Thanks

Comment: the `coord =>  ( coord.coords)` part is the success callback, your mixing async/await and callbacks, instead return a `new Promise` from getUserLocation and resolve/reject it instead in the callbacks abit ike `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
                    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);`

Comment: `window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` needs to return a `Promise` for the `await` keyword to work,

Comment: Thank you, that resolved it in my head and in my code.